# Files transfered from Windows have owner "Nobody". No file can be opened through Ethernet by Windows

Tags: networking, 14.04, permissions, samba, ownership

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 there is a problem with my local network.

In Ubuntu I can copy or open any Windows file from another PC by Ethernet. From Windows I can only copy files in both directions. All files copied to Ubuntu common folder obtain owner "nobody". Any file on Ubuntu machine cannot be edited with LibreOffice in Windows machine.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Set this in your smb.conf:

```
[MyShare]
comment = My Share
#other fields here for the share
path = /shares/MyShare
force user = thisuser
force group = thisgroup
```

(I got this from [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076293))

Answer (score 1):

sudo chown computerName:computerName /file or folder path/ -R

Ex : sudo chown computerName:computerName /var/www/html/project/js -R

Answer (score 0):

Thank You!
The problem can be solved different way using graphic interface (sorry for my translation from Ukrainian to English).

First the system may be updated to solve some bugs:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

If the sharing was created by Nautilus it may be cancelled. Rightclick the folder in Nautilus, select "Properties", select third tab, deselect first checkbox "Share folder" and click button "Change resource".

Install system-config-samba. It now works correctly:

sudo apt-get install system-config-samba

Launch system-config-samba from the administration menu in classicmenu-indicator or in the Unity launch bar or in a terminal

sudo system-config-samba

Use it usual way. At this moment in up-to-date system it works fine. It can create a Samba user related to a Linux user. So the network will be more safe.