# How do I make files copied over the network from my Windows computer be owned by me?

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a drive on my Ubuntu machine shared over a network, and one of the computers that can access it is a Windows 7 computer.

Whenever I am on my Windows computer and I copy a file to the Ubuntu shared folder, it appears as owned by nobody, and with limited permissions:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 nobody nogroup
```

I always have to go to the command line on the Ubuntu side and issue a `chown` command to make it so that I have permissions to edit the file. Until I do, I can't move or copy it, and it won't sync with Dropbox.

How can I make it so that when I copy files from my Windows machine they automatically are owned by me (I only have one user account on my Ubuntu machine) and I have the permission to edit and move them freely?

Comment: [Files transfered from Windows have owner “Nobody”. No file can be openned through Ethernet by Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/469753/283843)

Comment: `xcopy` can sometimes work better over a network (I don't know why it does but I experienced it today). You might be able to use the switches `/o` or `/x`. I am not really familiar with this though, and can't test. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true Ew @ my link source :) This only works if you are able to give some sort of permissions to Ubuntu in first place, so not sure if it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how your directory is shared on your network. If it is using Samba, edit the smb.conf and add the following two lines in the definiton of your share:

```
[yourshare]
...
force user = yourusername
force group = yourgroup
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems this worked. I added the two lines to force ownership under the `[global]` section, as I'm the only user on my network. Just going to confirm over a day before marking this as the definite solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with the --no-preserve flag in cp

```
cp --no-preserve=ownership source destination
```

edit: That will still have weird permissions (owner will be the user calling cp though). This will probably work better when copying from ntfs:

```
cp --no-preserve=ownership,mode source destination
```

That will match it to the bitmask of the folder being copied into, so if you are logged in as "user-a" and copy into a dir with drwxr-xr-x perms (0755) the files will be owned by "user-a" and have -rw-r--r-- perms (0644).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the Ubuntu side cause the shared directory doesn't have enough permission.

Since any files which is created in the directory has parent-child relation permission feature So it's a good chance to change **umask** of the directory.

Due to the wikipedia,

> In computing, umask is a command that determines the settings of a
>   mask that controls how file permissions are set for newly created
>   files

So I think changing the umask of the directory may has worth of testing.

To archive changing of **umask**,there are a lot of documentations and examples in the network.
wish to be worked.

Answer (score 0):

*If the other answers don't help you out, as a last option* you could write a small bash script that automatically gives you full permissions and ownership of just all files in your shared folder. You still would have to launch this one command manually, but you could avoid typing it for each file separately. Maybe there is also the possibility to make the script "watch" the folder and whenever it gets changed, permissions will be given immediately. Though I think this would only work while it is running and not detect changes between shutdown and next reboot.